# read unknown number of VTK files with LegacyVTKReader

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

Hi So I am using paraview "trace" tool to make a python script.
When I read the vtk files, the python script is using a command called "LegacyVTKReader" and then there is the name of all the VTK files that I have opened. something like this:

```
paraview = LegacyVTKReader( FileNames=  
['/home/afshinzkh/Desktop/DEM/Sample 1/paraview0500.vtk',  
'/home/afshinzkh/Desktop/DEM/Sample 1/paraview1000.vtk',  
'/home/afshinzkh/Desktop/DEM/Sample 1/paraview1500.vtk',  
'/home/afshinzkh/Desktop/DEM/Sample 1/paraview2000.vtk', 
'/home/afshinzkh/Desktop/DEM/Sample 1/paraview2500.vtk'])
```

now the problem is in every sample I have, there are different numbers of VTK files with different names. So I want to change the code in a way so that it works for all my samples. more prcisely I want to go to a folder and read all the VTK files in that folder.
like this:

```
paraview paraview = LegacyVTKReader( FileNames=  
['/home/afshinzkh/Desktop/DEM/Sample 1/*.vtk'])
```

is there a way to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do what I think you are asking. This will get a list of all files in a folder

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
# This is done to filter out directories
mypath = "path/to/my/dir"
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
for file in onlyfiles:
    paraview paraview = LegacyVTKReader( FileNames= [file])
    # do whatever else you do
```

This assumes you have a folder with only .vtk files. You can of course also easily add checks for that.

A bit cleaner would be to use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) instead.

```
import glob
# Returns list of path names that matches
onlyfiles = glob.glob( mypath + '*.vtk') 
for file in onlyfiles:
    paraview paraview = LegacyVTKReader( FileNames= [file])
    # do whatever else you do
```

Comment: or use glob: onlyfiles = glob.glob( mypath + '*.vtk')

Comment: True indeed! I'll add it as an alternative. I think glob will include all matching files in the subdirectories though?

Comment: look, there is a little indentation error before the for . Anyway no, glob works like the shell expansion, it will not include the files in the subdirectories